# "can't read Folder" error when calling sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to find "bots" inside a huge log file. They all log in, change password and log off all within one second.

I want to write Bash command that will show all profiles meeting following criteria:

- user logged in, user changed password, user logged off within same second (all 3 actions have to be done within 1 second)
- those actions (log in, change, log off) happen one after another with no other entries in between

`fxsciaqulmlk` is a typical profile name from the log file.

Small part of the log file:

```
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:42 +0200|178.57.66.225|faaaaaa11111| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:49 +0200|178.57.66.215|terdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:49 +0200|178.57.66.215|terdsfsdfsdf| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:49 +0200|178.57.66.215|terdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user changed profile| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciulmla| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciulmla| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciulmla| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:20:42 +0200|178.57.67.225|faaaa0a1111| - |user logged in| -
```

I wrote this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '
    /logged in\s*$/! d
    :1
    $! N
    /logged in\s*$/D
    /\(logged \(in\|off\)\|changed password\)$/! s/\n[^\n]*$//
    /logged off$/! b1
    ' /home/indra/Desktop/Untitled Folder/log.txt
```

but when I try to run this code I get this massage:

```
sed: can't read Folder/log.txt: No such file or directory
```

How to fix this?

Comment: what's the input file looking like and the expected output? Given dummy data, no error here.

Comment: expected output? >>>> show all profiles meeting following criteria:
 
- user logged in, user changed password, user logged of within same second (all 3 actions have to be done within 1 second)
- those actions (log in, change, log off) happend one after another with no other entires in between ..... from log.txt

Comment: not going to look into links, post minimal sample data here, read about [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You may well edit your question to make it clear, adding stuff in comments generally does not make things clearer.

Comment: I hope it's clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put quotes around `Untitled Folder` as it contains a space. And maybe start all sed input in the first column.

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '
/logged in\s*$/! d
:1
$! N
/logged in\s*$/D
/\(logged \(in\|off\)\|changed password\)$/! s/\n[^\n]*$//
/logged off$/! b1
    ' /home/indra/Desktop/"Untitled Folder"/log.txt
```

Comment: no error now but the script don't output any thing at bash

Comment: try the edited - start the sed stuff all in column 1